# What is the suitable phrase/word to say "break time"

Tags: word-choice

I currently use "休憩時間" to refer to break time, however not sure whether it is correct.
"break time" here is interval for rest/food etc. for employees, students etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

休憩時間 is a correct and legitimate word for 'break time': It is used in the Japanese Labour Law ([労働基準法](https://elaws.e-gov.go.jp/search/elawsSearch/elaws_search/lsg0500/detail?lawId=322AC0000000049)). The word can also be used in a casual conversation.